# UIWebView orientation issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that displays text. The text exceeds the height of the iphone screen so the user must scroll to get to text that goes beyond the iPhones screen.

I would like to keep the words that are at the top left part of the UIWebView, at the top left of the UIWebView during an orientation change.

So if the user is reading in portrait and the top left most text is "Welcome to the...." in portrait. I would like the SAME text to be at the top left when the device changes its orientation to landscape.

Is this functionality possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use javascript to achieve it.

First finding where the webview was before the rotation, finding the pageOffset after the rotation and using something like this to scroll:

```
NSString* goToOffsetFunc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" function pageScroll(xOffset){ window.scroll(xOffset,0); } "];
NSString* goTo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pageScroll(%f)", pageOffset];

[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:goToOffsetFunc];
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:goTo];
```

Other way is to get the scrollView inside the webView and scroll it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the idea of it is correct. But what I am missing is the algorithm for calculating the portraits y offset into a lanscape y offset. This algorithm would have to take the texts height, screen dimensions and portrait y's offset into consideration before it could produce a correct y offset for landscape to scroll too. 

Thanks anyways :)